# Sparse Matrix Multiplication using Linked Lists in C

Tags: c

I have two link list with non-zero number and i try to multiply the two link list and the result store it in a third link list. Not convert the link list to an array. The two list i create them in another function. Also on the lists i’ve created all the row and columns are like: if the table has 2 rows and 2 column and the first node is in the place 1 row and 0 col, the next node cant be on 0 row and 1 col. I know that the loop is wrong. Any help because i really have stuck to this.

```
typedef struct node         
{
    int     row;            
    int     column;         
    float   value;          
    struct  node * next;    
} node;


typedef struct table                
{
    node *  head;                   
    int     number_of_rows;         
    int     number_of_columns;      
}   table;

void create_new_node( node* start, table * input, float non_zero_element,
                              int row_index, int column_index ) {

        node *temp, *r;
        start = input->head;
        temp = start;
        if (temp == NULL) {
            temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->value = non_zero_element;
            temp->row = row_index;
            temp->column = column_index;
            temp->next = NULL;
            input->head = temp;

        } else {
            while (temp->next != NULL) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            r = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
            r->value = non_zero_element;
            r->row = row_index;
            r->column = column_index;
            r->next = NULL;
            temp->next = r;
        }
    }


    void Multables(table table1, table table2, table * table3) {

            node *currA = table1.head;
            node *currB;
            table3->number_of_rows = table1.number_of_rows;
            table3->number_of_columns = table2.number_of_columns;
            table3->head = NULL;
            node *currC = table3->head;

            if (table1.number_of_columns != table2.number_of_rows) {
                printf("the multiplication can't be done!!!\n");
                return;
            }

             float prod;
for (int i = 0; i < table3.number_of_rows; i++) {
    prod = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < table3.number_of_columns; j++) {
        currB=table2.head;
        for (int k = 0; k < table3.number_of_rows; k++) {
            printf("currA=%f ",currA->value);
            printf("currB=%f ",currB->value);
            if (currA->row == i && (currA->column == k && currB->row == k)) {
                prod += currA->value * currB->value;
                printf(" prod=%f ",prod);
            }
            currB = currB->next;
        }
        if (prod != 0) {
            create_new_node(currC, table3, prod, i, j);
        }
    }
    currA = currA->next;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

That's how i did it

```
    float search(node* start, table input, int row_index, int column_index) {

        start = input.head;
        float zero = 0;
        while(start != NULL) {
            if(start->row == row_index && start->column == column_index) {
                return start->value;
            }
            start = start->next;
        }
        return zero;
    }


 void Multables(table table1, table table2, table * table3) {


    if (table1.number_of_columns != table2.number_of_rows) {
        printf("the multiplication can'τ be done!!!\n");
        return;
    }

    node *currA = table1.head;
    node *currB = table2.head;
    table3->number_of_rows = table1.number_of_rows;
    table3->number_of_columns = table2.number_of_columns;
    table3->head = NULL;
    node *currC = table3->head;

    float prod = 0, t1 = 0, t2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < table1.number_of_rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table2.number_of_columns; j++) {
            prod = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < table1.number_of_columns; k++) {
                t1 = search(currA,table1,i,k);
                t2 = search(currB,table2,k,j);
                prod += t1 * t2;
            }
            if (prod != 0) {
                create_new_node(currC, table3, prod, i, j);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your "table" implementation but I would recommend you to re-assign CurrB to table2.head before the for loop. And make prod 0 again.
What does this code give as output? 
I searched for Sparse Matrix and multiplication on sparse matrices, and I guess you need more for loops. Computing i-j'th element of the result takes for loops too.

Comment: I edit my code. I have tried also with 3 loops but i don't get he results i want!